# Linq distinct on two columns

Tags: sql, linq

How can i select data from DB using LINQ and distinct results by two columns?

SQL:

```
SELECT distinct date, SSN
FROM tablename
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var query = (from t in tableName
             select new { t.date, t.SSN }).Distinct();
```